# DataTable Column DataTypes in OracleBulkCopy

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

I'm trying to use OracleBulkCopy to insert a large number of records from a `DataTable` into my database. Except, I'm not sure what DataTypes I have to use for the `DataTable` `Columns`. My database datatypes are `varchar2`, `datetime` and `numeric`. In the Oracle.DataAccess, I see `Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDBType` and `Oracle.DataAccess.Types`. What do I use for what?

Answer (score 0):

I use the Oracle.DataAccess.Client.DbType enum for column datatypes when doing ArrayBinding for large insertion of data and this works correctly